# Python For loop Overwriting dict

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-requests, lxml

I have a for loop to return the orders from a request to a online store. This then inserts the required elements into a dict. My issue is that when I have multiple items in an order it overwrites the dict with the last order from the request.

I can see there are multiple items on the order using the `print("this is an order")` in the code.

How do I increase the index in the dict so that instead of overwriting it, order items are appended to it.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
   #get specifics on each order with orderID from previous request
    tags2 = ('{http://publicapi.ekmpowershop.com/}ProductCode', '{http://publicapi.ekmpowershop.com/}ProductQuantity',
            '{http://publicapi.ekmpowershop.com/}ProductName', '{http://publicapi.ekmpowershop.com/}OrderDate',
            '{http://publicapi.ekmpowershop.com/}ProductPrice')

    for orderItem in xmlFormatter(ekmSingleOrderRequest(str(list(out.values())[0])), "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test2.xml").iter('{http://publicapi.ekmpowershop.com/}OrderItem'):
        out2 = {}
        #here we can the quantity of order items
        print("this is an order item")
        for child in orderItem:
            count = 0
            if child.tag in tags2:
                out2[child.tag[child.tag.index('}')+1:]] = child.text
```

Comment: put the orders in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list, to save each item:

```
    items = []
    for orderItem in xmlFormatter(ekmSingleOrderRequest(str(list(out.values())[0])), "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test2.xml").iter('{http://publicapi.ekmpowershop.com/}OrderItem'):
        out2 = {}
        #here we can the quantity of order items
        print("this is an order item")
        for child in orderItem:
            if child.tag in tags2:
                out2[child.tag.split('}',1)[1]] = child.text
    items.append(out2)
```

Comment: Cheers, I knew it'd be something simple I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that you use a dictionary? Could you use a pandas data frame instead?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["A","B"])

for orderItem in xmlFormatter(ekmSingleOrderRequest(str(list(out.values())[0])), "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test2.xml").iter('{http://publicapi.ekmpowershop.com/}OrderItem'):
        out2 = {}
        #here we can the quantity of order items
        print("this is an order item")
        tobeappended = {}
        for child in orderItem:
            count = 0
            if child.tag in tags2:
                tobeappended["A"] = child.tag[child.tag.index('}')+1:]
                tobeappended["B"] = child.text
                df = df.append(tobeappended,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The Dataframe-Indices should not be `A` and `B`, but the tags, the OP is using.

Comment: What is the benefit gained from using `pandas` here?